# Theme the User Edit Profile page

Tags: users

I am using the [Edit Profile](http://drupal.org/project/edit_profile) module.

This module takes all the fields attached to a user profile and displays them on a separate tab located at yoursite.com/user/[USERID]/edit-profile.

I would like to theme the fields on this edit profile page. How can I do it?

I have tried two approaches but none seem to work:

**Approach 1: Tpl.php suggestion from theme developer**

Theme Developer suggests to use the following template: `page--user--edit-profile.tpl.php`
This however has two problems:
1) It affects the whole page and not just the user profile form.
2) It doesn't seem possible to access the fields on the user profile from this template.

**Approach 2: template.php**

The form ID of the user profile edit form is `edit-profile-user-profile-form` so I used the following code in my template.php file to override it:

```
function THENAME_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {

    return array(
        'edit-profile-user-profile-form' => array(
            'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
            'template' => 'templates/edit/user-profile',
            'render element' => 'form',
            ),
    );


}
```

This, however, only over rides the main user profile page and not the fields on the edit tab. Can anyone help?

Comment: look for my [answer on adding css to user pages](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37192/how-can-i-write-url-specific-css/37193#37193)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured this out.

The solution is to use approach 2 (in my opening post). However, in the template.php file, you have to remove all the dashes from the form ID (`edit-profile-user-profile-form`) and replace them with underscores.

So the code in template.php would be as follows:

```
function THENAME_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {

    return array(
        'edit_profile_user_profile_form' => array(
            'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
            'template' => 'templates/edit/user-profile',
            'render element' => 'form',
            ),
    );
```

}

Next create a file called `user-profile.tpl.php` and save it in templates/edit.

In the `user-profile.tpl.php` file, use the following code to print out the fields:

```
<?php print drupal_render($form['field_NAME_OF_FIELD']); ?>
```

Comment: is this a working version i tried using the template and placed it in my theme module file but the template isnt being detected. I am using drupal 7.

Comment: @Alexander. Yes this works. Make sure it is your theme directory (not module file) and that you have cleaned the cache.

Comment: @big_smile You mentioned in your question that you want to theme the fields in edit profile page. Right? Why not just use css?

Answer (score 0):

I think, this may work. Little modification.

function THENAME_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {

```
return array(
    'user_profile_form' => array(
        'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
        'template' => 'templates/edit/user-profile-edit',
        'render element' => 'form',
        ),
);
```

}

Next go to your theme (sites/all/theme/yourtheme/) and create file called user-profile-edit file inside templates/edit/. Try to dpm($form). You will get whole form elements. You can render one by one whichever you needed.