# How can i write url specific CSS

Tags: theming, uri

How can i write css for content of the dynamic url page like 'http://mysitename/user/23/prayerrequests'. Here 23, assume user id. I want to effect conent div css of this dynamic url's.

Comment: What do you mean URL specific ? Do you want the CSS to change for every user ?

Comment: yaa kantu, dynamically user number changes...like user/2/prayerrquest, user/3/prayerrequests etc..like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the following, it implements [`drupal_add_css()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/6).

```
if($_GET['q']=="user/23/prayerrequests") {
  drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . '/custom_stylesheet.css', 'theme', 'all');
}
```

**Edit 1:**
If you want this to be able to do it for all users, you could use [me aliases](http://drupal.org/project/me) module. It enables you to use `me` in place of `%uid`.
So, the code would become

```
// "me" from the code is automatically replaced by uid of current logged in user.
if($_GET['q']=="user/me/prayerrequests") {
  drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . '/custom_stylesheet.css', 'theme', 'all');
}
```

**Edit 2:**
You can use the variable `global $user` in the above code. You'll not need to install me aliases module.

```
//replace THEME with your theme name
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  global $user;
  if($user->uid == 0) {
    return;
  }
  elseif ($_GET['q']=="user/".$user->uid."/prayerrequests") {
    drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . '/custom_stylesheet.css', 'theme', 'all');
}
```

Don't forget to clear the caches.

Comment: Indrock, Can i use '%' in the place 23 for dynamic change and where this line has to write..in page.tpl?

Comment: I'm not so sure. Look for the edit, I've suggested a work around for the same.

Comment: put above code in THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) located in your theme template.php file, don't forget to change THEME with your actual theme_name

Comment: Is there any other option apart from 'me' ..placeholder like * or % etc...........

Comment: look for the edit above. also added the code to `function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables)` as per @svetlio 's suggestion

Comment: Great Indrockk...You are  Rock............

Comment: If it solved your query, consider accepting it..

Comment: ya sure indrock

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4141/discussion-between-thirupathi-and-indrock)

Comment: Just mistakenly clciked on barroponto, any way site actuall css file is not overriding when i go to user/x/pr url..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load a different stylesheet for every user, then this would work:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page($variables) {
  if (arg(0) == 'user' && is_int(arg(1)) && (empty(arg(2)) || arg(2) == 'view') {
    drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . '/user-' . arg(1) . '.css';
  }
}
```

However, if what you're looking for is a dynamic stylesheet, I'd recommend against that — but it can be achieved with [Less](http://drupal.org/project/less) or [Sassy](http://drupal.org/project/sassy).

Comment: This will help to use different CSS for different users of the site. But, I think OP is looking for a solution to add the same CSS to a specific page only, for all users.

Comment: Then drupal_add_css is the solution, anyway. But if OP wants to add a custom css for all pages, based on logged in user, just use `global $user` and get the `$user->id`. Beware that `$user->id = 0` for anonymous users.

Comment: yes, I have that implemented in my answer.

Comment: Why don't you just use body classes? It's far easier and better to theme pages when you include the current path and all arguments there.

Answer (score 1):

If your not looking to write your own module, you can also look into something like [Themekey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey):

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other properties.