# Profile2 Template for edit page

Tags: users

i already searched all relevant drupal sites - but without success.
I have to create a own template file for the "edit user profile" site of the module Profile2.

As far as i know, i have to hook the new templatefile in the template.php of my theme - but what keywords and syntax do i need to accomplish that?

Every hint would be great!
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I did this way to create my own "edit user profile" for profiles of profile2 module.

```
function customtheme_theme() {    
    $items = array();
    $items['user_profile_form'] = array(
        'render element' => 'form',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'customtheme') . '/templates',
        'template' => 'user-profile-form',
        'preprocess functions' => array(
             'customtheme_preprocess_user_profile_form'
        ),
    );
    return $items;
}
```

- I put **customtheme_theme()** function into my **template.php** file of **customtheme theme**. (a custom theme that i used for my website)
- After that i created the template file **user-profile-form.tpl.php** and placed in the **templates** folder of my theme.
  The **customtheme_preprocess_user_profile_form** function you can use that for changing some variables before render the profile form or if you dont need any changes you can remove the preprocess_functions.
- After add the **customtheme_theme()**, create **user-profile-form.tpl.php** template. You have to clear cache and you can see the layout change for user-profile-form.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this very detailed reply. 
I made all entrys in the template.php and user-profile-form.tpl.php and cleared all cache multiple times. 
Unfortunately the edit site does not change. 
Iam confused about the $items['user_profile_form'] keyword - is there any reference, because in other forums i read something about $items['user_profile2_edit']?

I keep on trying and will reply as soon as it works! Thx

Comment: So you are asking about separate tpl file for **profile2** profile edit page ?

Comment: Exactly! I guess Stone Vos answer should work ... but iam still searching the reason why the new tpl file doesnt show up.

Comment: Have you checked this question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31203/theme-the-user-edit-profile-page

Comment: Hm, i checked it out, but the self-answered question is about another module. Approach 2 is very similar to Stone Vos reply and i cant detect any significant differences :/

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Kinda bussy the last weeks and havent made any progress on this topic. Iam still wondering, if the $items['user_profile_form'] = array(
... is the correct keyword. I changed the user-register template successfully with the hook 'user_register_form', so iam sure the template file is parsed correctly.

Comment: to be more precisely: for my understanding the hook should be something linke 'user_profile2_edit' or similar ... is there any reference?!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I accomplished different template files for each Profile2 Edit Page.

First, form_alter to set up the form #theme properly

```
function THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
    if ($form['#user_category'] === 'writers') {
      $form['#theme'] = 'profile2_writers_edit_form';
    } else if ($form['#user_category'] === 'secondary') {
      $form['#theme'] = 'profile2_secondary_edit_form';
    } else if ($form['#user_category'] === 'main') {
      $form['#theme'] = 'profile2_main_edit_form';
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can set up the templates this way

```
function THEME_theme() {
  return array(
    'profile2_writers_edit_form' => array(
      'arguments' => array(
        'form' => NULL,
      ),
      'template' => 'profile2-writers-edit',
      'render element' => 'form',
    ),
    'profile2_secondary_edit_form' => array(
      'arguments' => array(
        'form' => NULL,
      ),
      'template' => 'profile2-secondary-edit',
      'render element' => 'form'
    ),
    'profile2_main_edit_form' => array(
      'arguments' => array(
        'form' => NULL,
      ),
      'template' => 'profile2-main-edit',
      'render element' => 'form',
    ),
  );
}
```

Now all you have to do is add the files to your theme folder and clear cache. In this case I ended up with the following files for Profile2

```
profile2-writers-edit.tpl.php
profile2-secondary-edit.tpl.php
profile2-main-edit.tpl.php
```

A basic tpl should look something like this

```
<article id="node-user-edit" class="profile2-user-edit writers-profile">
  <?php print drupal_render_children($form); ?>
  <?php print drupal_render($form['#submit']); ?>
</article>
```

Print fields singularly like so

```
<?php print drupal_render($form['FIELD_NAME']); ?>
```

Comment: This is a good example IMO. I have been trying to work out how I need to set up 3 custom Edit pages for 3 member types. Your example makes good sense and explains what to do by example. You should put your example on the drupal.org site as no other clear concise examples show how to add 'more than 1' profile2 edit page. Thanks for the effort & time amigo.