# Custom template for each profile2 profile type edit form

Tags: 7, theming, forms, ajax

I am working on a Drupal 7 site and for a few days now, I've been struggling with this problem: I am trying to create a custom template for the edit profile form, but there are more profile types. I managed to create the template but it does not work properly. I am able to save all the fields except the image field. When I hit remove button, the filed disappears completely, then I have to hit save two times for the image to be actually removed. Also, if I add an image, then press upload, I get a warning:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'profile2_form' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 841 of /var/www/html/hxl_drupal/includes/form.inc).)

If I hit save twice, the image gets saved.

I tried a lot of websites, including these:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548116/drupal-7-load-profile2-programmatically
- [Profile2 Template for edit page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/profile2-template-for-edit-page) which were the closest ones to my issue.

I should also mention that the form is submitted through AJAX and that I use ctools module to open it in modal.

Below you can see the code.

#### `template.php`

```
/*
* Implements hook_form_alter()
*/

function customtheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
    if ($form['#user_category'] === 'partner_user') {
      $form['#theme'] = 'profile2_partner_user_edit_form';
    } else if ($form['#user_category'] === 'advisor_user') {
      $form['#theme'] = 'profile2_advisor_user_edit_form';
    }
  }
}

/*
*implements hook_theme()
*/

function customtheme_theme() {
  return array(
    'profile2_partner_user_edit_form' => array(
      'arguments' => array(
        'form' => NULL,
      ),
      'template' => 'templates/profile2--partner-user-edit',
      'render element' => 'form',
    ),
    'profile2_advisor_user_edit_form' => array(
      'arguments' => array(
        'form' => NULL,
      ),
      'template' => 'templates/profile2--advisor-user-edit',
      'render element' => 'form'
    ),
  );
}
```

#### `custom_module.module`

```
/**
* hook_menu
*/
function custom_module_menu() {
$items['profile/user-advisor_user_edit/%user/%ctools_js'] = array(
  'page callback' => 'profile_advisor_user_edit',
  'page arguments' => array(2,3),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'user'),
  'file' => 'user.pages.inc',
);

$items['profile/user-partner_user_edit/%user/%ctools_js'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'profile_partner_user_edit',
    'page arguments' => array(2,3),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'user'),
    'file' => 'user.pages.inc',
  );

    return $items;
}
```

I will post only the code for this profile type, because except the key word advisor_user.

```
function profile_advisor_user_edit($user, $js = FALSE ){
  if ($js){

   ctools_include('user.pages', 'user', '');
   ctools_include('modal');
   ctools_include('ajax');


   $form_state = array(
   'ajax' => TRUE,
   'title' => t('Edit Profile'),
   'user_id' => $user,
    );

   $form_state['build_info'] = array(
   'args' => array($user),
   );

   $output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('profile2_advisor_user_edit_form', $form_state);    

    if (!empty($form_state['executed'])) {
      $output = array();
      $output[] = ctools_modal_command_dismiss();
    }

  print ajax_render($output);
  exit;
}else{
  module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages');
  $user_edit_form =     drupal_get_form('profile2_advisor_user_edit_form',$user);
  return drupal_render($user_edit_form);
}
```

}

The `profile2--advisor-user-edit.tpl.php` file I will post the code only for this profile type because they are pretty much the same.

```
 module_load_include('inc', 'profile2_page', 'profile2_page'); // Include profile2_page module

$profile2 = profile2_by_uid_load($user->uid, 'advisor_user');
$entity_form = entity_ui_get_form('profile2', $profile2, 'edit'); // Or 'add'
print render($entity_form['profile_advisor_user']['field_picture']);
print render($entity_form['profile_advisor_user']['field_first_name']);
print render($entity_form['profile_advisor_user']['field_last_name']);
print render($entity_form['profile_advisor_user']['field_role']);
print render($entity_form['profile_advisor_user']['field_bio']);
print render($entity_form['profile_advisor_user']  ['field_interest_topics']);
print render($entity_form['profile_advisor_user']['field_interest_areas']);
unset($entity_form['extra_fields']) //here I unset the fields that I don't want to appear in the form
print render($entity_form);
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Notice that Drupal doesn't use any template.tpl.php file.

Comment: That's right. Sorry, I meant template.php. It is the one from the custom theme. I edited the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Loading form using [`module_load_include()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_load_include/7.x) isn't advised, you should use [`form_load_include()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_load_include/7.x) instead, so the include file is loaded whenever the form is processed. That's why you've issues on form submit.

> Use this function instead of `module_load_include()` from inside a form constructor or any form processing logic as it ensures that the include file is loaded whenever the form is processed. In contrast to using `module_load_include()` directly, `form_load_include()` makes sure the include file is correctly loaded also if the form is cached.

Otherwise define your form using [`hook_forms`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_forms/7.x), so Drupal knows where to find it (in which file).

> By default, when `drupal_get_form()` is called, the system will look for a function with the same name as the form ID, and use that function to build the form. If no such function is found, Drupal calls this hook.