# Theming Profil2 module

Tags: theming

i'm on **drupal 7**, using a premium theme "**fundedvisual**" and i'm trying to do some templates on a sub theme called "**fundedvisual_subtheme**".

I'm a noob in this, so maybe i did something wrong...

I have Profil2 module with 2 different profil types here the system names : "**investor**" and "**project_creator**".

i followed the answer of **jeff_shamley** in this post : [Profile2 Template for edit page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/profile2-template-for-edit-page)

i created a **template.php** file in "**/sites/all/themes/fundedvisual_subtheme/**" with this in it :

```
function fundedvisual_subtheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
if ($form['#user_category'] === 'investor') {
  $form['#theme'] = 'profile2_investor_edit_form';
} else if ($form['#user_category'] === 'project_creator') {
  $form['#theme'] = 'profile2_project_creator_edit_form';
} else if ($form['#user_category'] === 'main') {
  $form['#theme'] = 'profile2_main_edit_form';
}
  }
}

function fundedvisual_subtheme_theme() {
  return array(
'profile2_investor_edit_form' => array(
  'arguments' => array(
    'form' => NULL,
  ),
  'template' => 'profile2-investor-edit',
  'render element' => 'form',
),
'profile2_project_creator_edit_form' => array(
  'arguments' => array(
    'form' => NULL,
  ),
  'template' => 'profile2-project_creator-edit',
  'render element' => 'form'
),
'profile2_main_edit_form' => array(
  'arguments' => array(
    'form' => NULL,
  ),
  'template' => 'profile2-main-edit',
  'render element' => 'form',
),
  );
}
```

Then i made 3 files in "**/sites/all/themes/fundedvisual_subtheme/templates**" :

```
profile2-investor-edit.tpl.php
profile2-project_creator-edit.tpl.php
profile2-main-edit.tpl.php
```

with this in it :

```
<?php echo "pouet" ?>
```

Then i cleared the cache a million time :'D

Annnnnnnd nothing show up except the default system profile :/

Did i forget something ?
Thx in advance !

**Edit : i wonder if i can just embed these forms pages in views it would be nice, instead of creating templates with that i could just modify my style.css**

**Edit2 : one of my comments : to be more precise i have a general page called "my account" and in it i have the header menu on the top, below an image with a title, below another menu bar and below the content of each "button" from that menu bar.
Each time i click on a button from my menu i want to keep that template, so if i click on "profile" in my menu bar, it should be exactly the same except the title and the content. Is that possible ?**

Answer (score 0):

If the whole point of this is to be able to add wrappers around fields, an alternate option would be to use the [field group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module. Here is a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GU_tb4K-f4) on it.

Comment: This is not what i search, to be more precise i have a general page called "my account" and in it i have the header menu on the top, below an image with a title, below another menu bar and below the content of each "button", each time i click on a button from my menu i want to keep that template, so if i click on "profile" in my menu bar, it should be exactly the same except the title and the content. Is that possible ?